# Share current slide position in PDF over the Internet

Tags: conferencing

Is there a way to share the current slide which I'm looking at, to synchronize my view with someone over the  Internet?

I don't want to share the image of my screen; for a high-definition screen, this would need a high bandwidth, and I can share in advance the PDF with the other person. I'd really just like that, when I press "next slide" in my machine, the other party's view of the current document (e.g. a PDF) also changes, in a synchronized way. In other words, a poor's man screen sharing.

Is there some software which does it already? Otherwise, is there a way to "control" some process in the remote machine without having to give full keyboard/mouse control for the other user?

Comment: There are services that allow you to share specific applications, services like GoToMeeting, there are others but service recomendations are not on topic here at Superuser.

Comment: I was considering a more "ad hoc" solution, i.e. maybe coding a small socket-based script in Python or so (in which case I'm not sure here or Stackoverflow would be the best site)...

Comment: At this point a question like this would be closed at Stackoverflow. There is an certain level of expectation and right now you have a "general" idea of what you want which does not make a very good Stackoverflow question.

Comment: OK, thanks for the indication anyway, I'll close it (if I manage to find how to do it) and ask again when I'm more certain of what I need.

Comment: seems crystal clear to me

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can get a more specific answer than mine, but this is the general idea.

What you could look for is a Command or small program that can go to the next slide in powerpoint. This could be a program that just sends SPACE to the screen

Then you need to look how to execute that command remotely

As you say, a socket based script, but then you'll have to concern yourself with port forwarding. You could just set up port forwarding at your end, and they connect. And the program when started, listens for a space and when it hears it it sends a space to be executed on the connected machines.

You could ask some individual questions on stackoverflow that lead you to making it, but I don't think they'll be keen on writing your program for you.